# How can I use preg_match_all to seperate this string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm wondering how you can use preg_match_all to seperate this string

> 2:18 textextextextextext,sdfdsfd:,fdg

So it will return an array that looks like this:

```
array(
       0 => 2
       1 => 18
       2 => textextextextextext,sdfdsfd:,fdg
)
```

Basically removing the first colon

Comment: I think doing some effort to learn regex will help.

Comment: looks like all you need is preg_split using colon and space as deliminators

Comment: @Awni I have updated my post can you check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what you want to use is `preg_match()` and not `preg_match_all()` (based on your desired output).

You could then use a regex like:

```
(\d+):(\d+)\s*(.*)
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Nuejjn/1)

Which in PHP using `preg_match()` would look like this:

```
$pattern = "/(\d+):(\d+)\s*(.*)/";
$string = "2:18 textextextextextext,sdfdsfd:,fdg";
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

Doing `print_r($matches)` would output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2:18 textextextextextext,sdfdsfd:,fdg
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 18
    [3] => textextextextextext,sdfdsfd:,fdg
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a formatted string:

```
print_r(sscanf("2:18 textextextextextext,sdfdsfd:,fdg", "%d:%d %s"));
```